# Is it possible to derive the sum to product and product to sum trig formulae directly from Euler's formula?

Tags: trigonometry

I know of Euler's formula being used to derive the compound angle formula quickly using $e^{i(a+b)}$. But what about the sum/product identities? The compound angle formula is quite easy to remember actually, the but sum/product never seems to stick with me. I know you can derive them *using* the compound angles formula, but is there another way that is faster?

It doesn't even have to be math-related, but a mnemonic or intuitive analysis of these formulae which will let them stick in my head.

Comment: For the first formula, you just have to apply $\mathrm e^{i(a+b)}=\mathrm e^{ia}\,\mathrm e^{ib}$ if that is what you have in mind. For the second formula, I know no other way than practising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need the complex definitions of the sine and cosine.

$$e^{ia}\pm e^{ib}=e^{i(a+b)/2}(e^{i(a-b)/2}\pm e^{i(b-a)/2})=\begin{cases}2e^{i(a+b)/2}\cos\frac{a-b}2,\\2ie^{i(a+b)/2}\sin\frac{a-b}2\end{cases}\\$$

$$\begin{align}c+c\to\ \ \ 2cc\\c-c\to-2ss\\s+s\to\ \ \ 2sc\\s-s\to\ \ \ 2cs\end{align}$$

$$\frac{e^{ia}\pm e^{-ia}}2\frac{e^{ib}\pm e^{-ib}}2=\frac12(e^{i(a+b)}\pm e^{-i(a+b)})+\frac12(e^{i(a-b)}\pm e^{-i(a-b)})$$

$$\begin{align}cc\to\ \ \ \frac{c+c}2\\cs\to\ \ \ \frac{s-s}2\\sc\to\ \ \ \frac{s+s}2\\ss\to-\frac{c-c}2\end{align}$$

Comment: thanks! this was what i was looking for

Comment: but doesn't the complex definition of $\sin$ have an $i$ in the denominator? Where did that go?

Comment: @user71207: you need to add it depending on sign. I didn't want to clutter with that.

Comment: what do you mean by that [add]? I don't understand why, but I think it has something to do with the negatives in $c-c$ and $ss$

Comment: @user71207: just fix the formulas.